# How to detect average pitch in a time-formatted sound wave?

Tags: audio, audio-analysis

For a sound wave input like the ones generated by OpenAL microphone capture, how can one go about detecting the "average" pitch in the wave? (e.g. if it's a recording of a violin at 440 hz, I want to return ~440 hz). What's the most basic/intuitive way? Is there a reason to use a different method?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest searching for previous questions (of which there have been lots) of this nature, usually from questioners wanting to build instrument tuners.

Comment: In fact, this question is asked so often, I created a blog entry to explain one of the most common methods: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html